Is it possible to shrink the size of chapter title text?
If possible I would like to get the following chapter title:

onto one line, but usually I can't add things into a \chapter{} without LaTeX freaking out with all kinds of error codes.  Is it possible to do something like
\chapter{Introduction\thinspace to\thinspace Logic...}

or
\chapter{\begin{small}Introduction to Logic \& Mathematical Proofs\end{small}}

that the compiler will accept and display properly?

Answers to your questions will depend in part on which document class is in use. So, do please tell us which document class you employ.

^I'm using the book class.

The standard text width in the book class is 345pt, but your picture shows you have a larger width (at least 400pt) and you're already cheating by using \huge size for the title (the same as for the top line with “Chapter 2”).
Unfortunately, the whole title, in \huge size, is 467pt wide, which is about 2.5cm (almost one inch). There's no hope to make it one line unless you scale the title down.
Now compare. I set the text width to 400 pt to emulate your setup. You see in the second example that scaling is out of question.
The only feasible alternative is to split the title across lines by choosing the best break point (after “and”).
Using \& to save a bit of space is not a choice: you're not doing advertising, but mathematics.

This is the source of the example. Remember that, if you have formatting instructions in the argument, such as \\, the optional argument should be used.
Don't do resizing under any circumstances.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=400pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
% just to get several headers
% on the same page for comparison
\let\clearpage\relax\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\vspace*{-50pt}

\chapter[Introduction to Logic \& Mathematical Proofs]{%
  \huge Introduction to Logic \& Mathematical Proofs}

\vspace*{-25pt}\hrule\vspace*{-25pt}

\chapter[Introduction to Logic and Mathematical Proofs]{%
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    Introduction to Logic and Mathematical Proofs%
  }%
}

\vspace*{-25pt}\hrule\vspace*{-25pt}

\chapter[Introduction to Logic and Mathematical Proofs]{%
  Introduction to Logic and \\ Mathematical Proofs
}

\endgroup

\end{document}


Thanks for answering.  I'm fine with that size for all of the other chapters, that one just has the longest title and I just need to change the size for it specifically.  Why is the [ ] necessary before the { } after \chapter?  Is it possible to just do \chapter{\small Introduction...}?

@Nate You want to produce a table of contents, don't you? Well, try…
